# Can I use links in comments?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

I tried and failed [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/66278/plants-under-different-sunlight). Please tell me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: For example, [here's my answer.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289020/278543)

Comment: I asked something similar and got some great answers -- you might want to [check this out.](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/63259/…)

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Example of my [answer]( http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289020/278543)

Comment: There's a space before the hyperlink; that's why it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

I *think* (based on the output) that you used a space where you shouldn't.
This won't work:

```
I asked something similar and got some great answers -- you might want to 
[check this out.]( http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/63259/...)
```

```
                  ^
```

but this will:

```
I asked something similar and got some great answers -- you might want to 
[check this out.](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/63259/...)
```

Comment: I think you are right.

Answer (score 1):

.To use links in comments, use the following format:

```
[text](hyperlink)
```

You have a space before your hyperlink. As I said, there shall be no spaces in the hyperlink, before or after.

Comment: I thought that is what I did? perhaps I had to edit out something? Or I added a space?

Comment: There can be no space

Comment: okay I will try [here](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/66278/plants-under-different-sunlight)